# Workbox img GET third url net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED when offline

Tags: reactjs, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, workbox

My project needs to support offline mode and use react.
It will be embedded in other customers' PWA apps.
I package project by webpack 3.
The project is that the user will click the button and show the download page until all resources are ready.
It works well for the local file like "launcher.bundle.js", "local base64 image", "http//api fetch query"
I test it in localhost, prepare all downloaded resources then change the network condition to offline.
To get the third-party URL, it will show "GET URL net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED"
But I already fetch that URL.
Could someone tell me what's wrong with my code?

## Constructor

### webpcak 3

```
  new CopyWebpackPlugin([
    {
      from: 'src/index.html',
      to: 'index.html',
    },
    {
      from: 'src/service-worker.js',
      to: 'service-worker.js',
    }
  ]),
```

### index.js

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  // Use the window load event to keep the page load performant
  window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('./service-worker.js');
  });
}

App.openLaucher()

App.openDownload()
```

### Download page structor

```
export default class OfflineMode extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount() => {
    this.downloadFiles()
  }

  downloadFiles = async () => {
    await someDonwloadfunction()
  }

  render() {
    <div>{this.state.progress}</div>
  }
}
```

### Complete service-worker.js

```
importScripts('https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/6.4.1/workbox-sw.js');

workbox.googleAnalytics.initialize();

const cacheName = 'webmodule:network-first';
const networkFirst = new workbox.strategies.NetworkFirst({
  cacheName,
  matchOptions: {
    ignoreSearch: true,
    ignoreVary: true
  },
  plugins: [
    new workbox.cacheableResponse.CacheableResponsePlugin({statuses: [0, 200]}),
    new workbox.rangeRequests.RangeRequestsPlugin(),
  ],
});

workbox.routing.registerRoute(/^https:\/\/somewhere\//, networkFirst);

workbox.routing.registerRoute(/.*\.(?:html|js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|svg|gif|json)/, networkFirst);

workbox.routing.registerRoute(/^localhost\//, networkFirst);

self.addEventListener('install', function (event) {
  event.waitUntil(self.skipWaiting());
});

self.addEventListener('activate', function (event) {
  event.waitUntil(self.clients.claim());
});
```

### content

```
export default class launcher extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    <div>
      <img crossOrigin="anonymous" src={'https://www.keycdn.com/img/support/cors.png'} />
    </div>

  }
}
```

### Info screenshot

#### Fetch success

[image]

#### error log

[image]

#### query local file

[image]

#### query third-party URL

[image]

#### service worker

[image]

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Because I use the iframe structure.
The image can't emit the worker.
We need to transform the image URL to blob file.

```
<img src={blob}>
```

Using this way can work for me.